# "Java Web Start” starts sporadic on some machines

Tags: java, windows, java-web-start, jnlp

I am almost to give up by finding a solution on some client machines (Windows 7, Firefox 41, IE 10).

**The problem:** one `Java Web Start` application sometimes does not start from browser: a splash screen appears saying *Java Starting*... and then nothing happens! It does not even try to check/download the resource files, or write into java cache, no entries are found in the `Windows Event Log`.

**I have tried:**

1. Reinstall JRE (8u73)
2. Clear java cache (via control panel)
3. Clear browser's cache
4. Enable tracing and logging (nothing is written then)
5. Reduce the heap size to 512M
6. `deployment.trace.level=all` (still nothing is written)
7. `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` (no affect)
8. `JPI_PLUGIN2_DEBUG=1`,`JPI_PLUGIN2_VERBOSE=1` (no affect)
9. `jstack browser-pid` (attach is not possible not HotSpot VM!?)

Even without applying any changes, after some waiting, **sometimes** the application **does** start from the browser!?!?

Following behavior is observed: a `javaws` process starts and then disappears, sometimes(rarely) following error message is thrown: c++ runtime error ...`jp2launcher.exe`... can not be started...R6016 - not enough space for thread data

BUT it always works if started per `javaws.exe http://...xyz.jnlp` command!?!?

Comment: Have you gone through this [troubleshooting link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html)? Here's another [thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912676/243373) dealing with this problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your response TT! I have tried the "troubleshooting" and "thread on SO" with no success...